# Не работает метод .split в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть код:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = f'https://www.kufar.by/l/r~minsk/sistemnye-bloki'
responce = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(responce, "lxml")

pc = soup.find_all("a", class_="kf-aYRc-91bed")

for i in pc:
    print(i)
```

в данном случае:

```py
i = <a class="kf-aYRc-91bed" href="https://www.kufar.by/item/144054676" target="_blank"><div class="kf-aYRn-21906"><img alt="Компьютер Intel Core i3-8100  8GB  SSD" class="kf-aYEN-8bb5a lazyload" data-src="https://yams.kufar.by/api/v1/kufar-ads/images/77/7701247529.jpg?rule=list_thumbs"/><div class="kf-ahmS-8e3b8"><span>Сегодня, 11:01</span></div><div class="kf-aYRU-6dc94"></div><div class="kf-aYRk-f86f4"></div></div><div class="kf-aYRB-5ae40"><div><h3 class="kf-aYoS-c30ed">Компьютер Intel Core i3-8100  8GB  SSD</h3><div class="kf-aYRX-aacef">Intel core i3, 8 гб, ssd, новое</div></div><div><div class="kf-aMmR-1748d"><span class="kf-aMmm-47851">860 р.</span></div><div class="kf-aYRY-b935e"><div class="kf-aYRC-d196b"></div><div class="kf-aHaN-c983e kf-aHqJ-00e8e"><span>Доставка по Беларуси・Рассрочка</span></div><div class="kf-ahmT-434fc"><span>Сегодня, 11:01</span></div></div></div></div></a>
```

И мне надо получить текст после `"alt="` и до `class="kf-aYEN-8bb5a"`. я придумал делать это все через `split()` и сделал вот такую функцию:

```py
def spliits(i):
    splits = i.split("alt=")
    name = splits[1]
    splits2 = name.split('class="kf-aY')
    name = splits2[0]
    return name<code lang="python">

print(spliits(i))
```

Если создать новый файл и сделать там переменную `i`, которую я писал выше, то функция сработает, но если я пытаюсь вызвать в основном коде после `print(i)`, то почему-то мне вылезает вот эта ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path", line 19, in <module>
    spliits(i)
  File "path", line 11, in spliits
    splits = i.split("alt=")
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам нужно получить значение атрибута alt, то можно сделать гораздо проще

```
for i in pc:
    print(i.find("img").get("alt")
```

Компьютер HP 700G1 SFF i5-4440S
Игровой компьютер
Майнинг ферма 152MH/s -RX580/480
...

Comment: Спасибо! Но вы не знаете почему не работает split? Интересно понять что я делаю не так

Comment: @In1t в первую очередь, потому что split - это метод строки. А i это не строка, у него другой тип данных (bs4.element.Tag). Поэтому в этой строке "splits = i.split("alt=")" нужно прописать метод text к i: "splits = i.text.split("alt=")". Ну а дальше вылезают другие проблемы:-)

Comment: Спасибки за ответ)